# How to distribute but skipping one level

Tags: functional-style, code-request, rule

I would like to write a `Rule` that mimics built-in `Distribute[]`, but one that distributes `Plus` over a function `f`, while skipping a level (which for me, has head=`List`).  Here are examples of what I need:

```
(*1*) f[x,c,d,{e+k}] -> f[x,c,d,{e}] + f[x,c,d,{k}]

(*2*) f[x,{2 a},b,{c-d}] -> f[x,{2 a},b,{c-d}] + f[x,{2 a},b,{-d}]

(*3*) f[x,{a+b},e,{g+2*h}] -> f[x,{a},e,{g}] + f[x,{b},e,{g}] + f[x,{a},e,{2*h}] + f[x,{b},e,{2*h}]
```

Useful facts about `f`:

1. First argument is *always* `x`.
2. Remaining arguments *always* have head `Symbol` or `List`.
3. The head `Plus` is always inside `List`.

Ultimately, I will use this `Rule` in `Replace` as in

```
expandOut[expr_] = Replace[expr, (*The Rule I need*)]
```

For speed reasons I would like to avoid using `ReplaceRepeated`.  Is this possible?

Comment: Why do you want to have these one element lists (`{e+k}`, `{e}`,`{k}`,`{c-d}`,`{-d}`, ...) in the inputs and outputs ? What is the meaning ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
exp1 = f[x, c, d, {e + k}];
exp2 = f[x, {2 a}, b, {c - d}];
exp3 = f[x, {a + b}, e, {g + 2*h}];

distF = # //. g_[i___, {j_ + k_}, l___] :> Distribute[g[i, HoldForm[{j}] + HoldForm[{k}], l]] &;
(* or Defer in place of HoldForm *)

distF /@ {exp1, exp2, exp3} 
(* {f[x,c,d,{e}]+f[x,c,d,{k}],
    f[x,{2 a},b,{c}]+f[x,{2 a},b,{-d}],
    f[x,{a},e,{g}]+f[x,{a},e,{2 h}]+f[x,{b},e,{g}]+f[x,{b},e,{2 h}]} *)
```

Or

```
distF2 = Distribute[Replace[#, {Plus[x___]} :> (HoldForm[List[#]] & /@ x), 1]] &

distF2 /@ {exp1, exp2, exp3} 
(* {f[x,c,d,{e}] + f[x,c,d,{k}],
    f[x,{2} {a},b,{c}] + f[x,{2} {a},b,{-d}],
    f[x,{a},e,{g}] + f[x,{a},e,{2 h}] + f[x,{b},e,{g}] + f[x,{b},e,{2 h}]} *)
```

Note: Somehow, `{2 a}` is converted to `{2}{a}` during the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Does it fit your needs?

```
f[i___, {j_ + k_}, l___] := f[i, {j}, l] + f[i, {k}, l]

f[x, c, d, {e + k}]

f[x, {2 a}, b, {c - d}]

f[x, {a + b}, e, {g + 2*h}]
```

> ```
> f[x, c, d, {e}] + f[x, c, d, {k}]
>
> f[x, {2 a}, b, {c}] + f[x, {2 a}, b, {-d}]
>
> f[x, {a}, e, {g}] + f[x, {a}, e, {2 h}] + f[x, {b}, e, {g}] +  f[x, {b}, e, {2 h}]
> ```

Comment: It looks like it works; but I still feel that it is still recursive.  There's no one-shot rule that will get this to work?

Comment: @QuantumDot yes it is. I don't know how to do this all at once in simple manner.

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAttributes[Plus, {Listable}];
dist[expr_] :=Distribute[expr /. x : {_Plus} :> Plus @@ Transpose[List @@@ x]]
```

Note: run the code more than once.